# How I can receive multiple images for save in a folder in laravel?

Tags: php, image, laravel, laravel-4

I'm creating a server that communicates with an android application, the device sends the server 4 images which I saved to a folder.

With pure php would be something like

```
        $nombreImagen1 = $conteo++;
        $carpeta = "../Files/noticias/";
        $formato = str_replace("image/", ".", $_FILES['imagen1']['type']);               
        $destino = $carpeta.$nombreImagen1.$formato; // Nombre de la ruta + foto
        while (file_exists($destino)){
            $nombreImagen1++;             
            $destino = $carpeta.$nombreImagen1.$formato; // Nombre de la ruta + foto                
        }
        copy($_FILES['imagen1']['tmp_name'],$destino); // subir archivo a desde el origen hasta el destino
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this:

```
$files = Input::file();
```

This will give you an array of files and you may use use `foreach` loop like this:

```
$targetPath = 'set target path here';
foreach ($files as $file) {
    $fileName = $file->getClientOriginalName();
    $file->move($targetPath, $fileName);
}
```

Read more on [documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/requests#files).